# Turn off the Desktop Cleanup Wizard popup forever

Tags: windows-xp, desktop, icons, notifications, disk-cleanup

Every one in a while, I get a notification asking me if I want to remove unused icons from the Windows XP desktop.

How can I turn off this notification forever?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pretty simple, just head over to the Display Properties -> Desktop -> Customize Desktop option and remove the checkbox.

I've written up a guide on how to do it: [Stop the Annoying "There are unused icons on your desktop" Popup Balloon](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/stop-the-annoying-there-are-unused-icons-on-your-desktop-popup-balloon/)

[image]

Comment: +1 For the shameless selfreference, but I would have linked your post if you hadn't ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not usually the type to link my own articles, but you might notice the link in the footer... we're all on the same team =)

Comment: Alternatively, use a non-medieval operating system.

Comment: Thank you.  One less occasional minor annoyance in my life :)

Comment: P.S.  It's for my work machine.  No choice in OS there.

Comment: @Alistair - suggesting that someone change OS isn't usually the answer. Most people have to work with Windows because it's their work machine, or the programs they have to use only run on Windows, or they're not as computer literate as you and don't want the perceived hassles of switching to Linux

Comment: @chris If its for your work machine, and you're on a domain, ask the Active Directory people to set it in Group Policy.  It is very simple policy that takes 2 clicks to enable, then nobody gets bothered by it anymore.

Comment: @Brian:  Unfortunately, our AD people are not what you'd consider co-operative. I think Tim Bray described it best:  

Enterprise veterans often come to associate “Security” and stupidity; officious second-raters who pollute your workplace and tools with ass-covering irritants that get in your way to no plausible end.